# jQuery inArray ignores all but last element

Tags: jquery

I'm using the `inArray` function of jQuery to check wether a user's password is in the list of commonly known passwords. This is the function I use:

```
if(jQuery.inArray(pswd.toLowerCase(), commonPass) != -1) {
    console.log("is in array");
} else {
    console.log("is NOT in array");
}
```

The function is wrapped inside a `keyUp` event that is tagged onto the password field (and ofcause, inside the jQuery `ready` method).

For testing purpose, this is the loaded array:

```
["password", "12345678"]
```

and this is the logged result of the `pswd` variable:

```
password
```

However, the code returns:

```
is NOT in array
```

I simply do not understand why.

**EDIT**
Aparenly my issue could not be reproduced. Here is the complete script:
http://pastebin.com/EdfP0XRQ

And the commonpass file contains:

```
password
12345678
```

Comment: works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/sy9n2ff7/ so you need to provide a complete example

Comment: The error must be before this method.

Comment: Ive attacted the comlete script.

Comment: where the text file? not possible to debug without the text file. what happens when you log `commonPass` after it reads in the data?

Comment: The line "For testing purpose, this is the loaded array:" above in the question is the console.log after the loading.